# Encoding: does it make sense trying to decode an ISO-8859-15 string with chinese characters into UTF-8 string?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-15

I have the following string encoded with ISO-8859-15 stored inside of a file:

```
DEBUG_RECEIVED: ????
```

The correct UTF-8 string though is:

```
DEBUG_RECEIVED: 测试手机
```

Does it make sense trying to convert those wrong `????` characters again into `测试手机` (therefore from ISO-8859-15 to UTF-8 again), or is it just impossible due to the fact that ISO-8859-15 is not sued for chinese characters and as it uses 8 bit per character, the 16 bit needed for chinese characters are simply lost?

When I try the following:

```
echo "DEBUG_RECEIVED: ????" | iconv -f iso-8859-15 -t utf-8
```

I still get `DEBUG_RECEIVED: ????` as output.

I am a bit confused about this, please, if you can clarify this detail, it would be great.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: The `?` might actually just be `?`, so, there might not be any information left of the original string.

Comment: It's not possible to represent Chinese characters directly in ISO-8859-15.

Comment: @tonix: Keith is right. ISO-8859-15 is meant for Western European languages, with few differences from ISO-8859-1.  Chinese is encoded using GB2312, GB18030 or Big5 instead, if not one of the UTFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whatever generated the 8859-15 string had to discard the information necessary to represent Chinese characters.

Lost info is lost – your Chinese characters seem to have been *replaced* by `?`, and there is nothing that can get them back.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your clarification!